# How do I install DupeGuru Music Edition?

Tags: software-installation, duplicate-files

I need to install DupeGuru Music Edition but I do not know what files do I have to download for installing the software. The instructions spoke about Quantal, Saucy, Raring, Precise. What do these terms mean? I am new to Ubuntu and I do not find the easy way to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those names are only [development codenames](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames). One easy way to discover what's your Ubuntu release is by running `lsb_release -rc` in a terminal.

---

You don't have to manually download anything in order to install DupeGuru ME, just add Hardcoded's [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/65926). Run the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hsoft/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dupeguru-me
```

The correct package and its dependencies will be automatically downloaded and installed, and updates will be offered when available.

Comment: currently: https://github.com/arsenetar/dupeguru/issues/484

Answer (score 1):

Quantal is an obsolete version,so you can install DupeGuru Music Edition in any one of these versions Saucy,Raring,Precise.

Comment: I cannot seem to install dupeguru in stock Raring without adding the hsoft PPA.

Comment: yes,you are correct.